# Block Editor: add an aria-label to an option inside a SelectControl

Tags: block-editor, dropdown, accessibility

I'm building a block that has, among other things, a FontAwesome icon. I'm currently letting users choose which icon by using a WP `<SelectControl>`.

For individual `<option>`s, there is a built-in way to add a label. For example:

```
<SelectControl
    value={ icon }
    options={[
        { label: '', value: 'fa-address-book' }
    ]}
/>
```

Combined with CSS this works great - the dropdown shows the icon itself, making it easy to select for those with good vision. However, I'd like to make this more accessible by adding an `aria-label` for each `<option>`.

I tried

```
<SelectControl
    value={ icon }
    options={[
        { label: '', value: 'fa-address-book', 'aria-label': 'Address book' }
    ]}
/>
```

but the `aria-label` does not actually render. Is there another way to add it?

The HTML output I'm looking for:

```
<select id="inspector-select-control-0" class="components-select-control__input">
    <option value="fa-address-book" aria-label="Address book"></option>
</select>
```

I would also be all right with using a screen reader only class in the label itself, but when I try this

```
<SelectControl
    value={ icon }
    options={[
        { label: '<span class="show-for-sr">Address book</span>', value: 'fa-address-book' }
    ]}
/>
```

the < and > tags show literally in the label rather than creating an actual separate HTML `<span>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Nathan's answer, but you can copy the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/components/src/select-control/index.js) and create your own `SelectControl` component based on that source. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/5ally/29a5b7f3e0c047e654b368ebd10908cb), with basically just the `aria-label` addition:

```js
<option
    key={ `${ option.label }-${ option.value }-${ index }` }
    value={ option.value }
    disabled={ option.disabled }
    aria-label={ option.ariaLabel || '' }
>
    { option.label }
</option>
```

And a sample `index.js` file demonstrating usage of the custom `SelectControl` component:

```js
import SelectControl from './select-control-custom'; // make sure the path is correct
import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';

const MySelectControl = withState( {
    size: '50%',
} )( ( { size, setState } ) => (
    <SelectControl
        label="Size"
        value={ size }
        options={ [
            { label: 'Big', value: '100%', ariaLabel: 'Aria label for Big' },
            { label: 'Medium', value: '50%', ariaLabel: 'Aria label for Medium' },
            { label: 'Small', value: '25%', ariaLabel: 'Aria label for Small' },
        ] }
    />
) );
```

I.e. Use the `ariaLabel` property/key to set the ARIA label. And the above is based on [the example here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/select-control#usage-1).

Comment: Thank you, Sally! That's working beautifully.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/components/src/select-control/index.js), right now it's not possible to add anything to an option inside the SelectControl besides a label, a value, an optional disabled keyword, and an id which is automatically generated from the label and value.